# Having an issue installing Pyrebase

Tags: python, pycryptodome, pyrebase

This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycryptodome
  Running setup.py clean for pycryptodome
Failed to build pycryptodome
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycryptodome, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install pycryptodome directly from `.whl` file. You can download it here: https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/pycryptodome/
If that doesn't work try updating pip: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a specific version of Pyrebase
In my case:

```
pip install pyrebase4==4.7.1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).